# Распечатать последовательность символов

Tags: delphi

В одной строке экрана вводится последовательность символов (тип char). Ввод завершается нажатием клавиши Enter. Распечатать, сохраняя последовательность, цифры, следом символ "=" и последовательность символов, представляющих собой сумму всех цифр. Между цифр вывести символ "+". Массивов не использовать. Работа в delphi. Подскажите ход написания этой программы. Буду признателен.

Comment: @Alexander009, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @Alexander009, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите ход написания этой
> программы

Если только ход...

1. Записываете вход в строку (ай-ай-ай... строка - тоже массив. Но увы. Без этого - только работая с потоком ввода-вывода).
2. Последовательно идете по этой строке, в блоке try-except, пытаясь выполнить StrToInt.
   В случае успеха, увеличиваете сумму на данное число, а строку ответа - на прочтенный символ. В случае неудачи отлавливаете исключение и продвигаетесь дальше на один символ.
3. Делаете обратное преобразование IntToStr.
4. Выводите строку ответа, =, преобразованное число.

Profit.

N.B.: IDE называется **Delphi**.